# Google Maps Android V2 debug and release key

Tags: android, debugging, release, google-maps-android-api-2

I recently got the release key from Google Maps Android V2; So before exporting the signing APK from eclipse; I updated the manifest, changing the debug API key from GMaps to the Release API keys.

Hours later I needed to debug something, so I ran the app on debug **but I didn't change the Manifest API key back to the debug one**. As far as I am concerned, the app is signed with the debug key machine, but it contains the release key from GMaps API. As far as I know, it was supposed **NOT TO WORK**. The GMaps DID work. So now I'm confused. Could you explain please

Comment: you changed the sha1 in the api console?

Comment: nope, in the console I kept both, the Release sha1 and the debug sha1, but in the debug app, the meta tag contians the release api key but not the debug one

Comment: Did you have to uninstall release version of the app before installing signed with debug key?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Have you tried to `clean` the project before recompiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new API (Version 2) you can have the same key for multiple sha-1 fingerprints.

Can it be that you have configured in your APIs Console, the API key with both your debug and release keystore fingerprint like so:

[image: Google APIs Console]

Comment: I have both sha-1 fingerprints on the console (the unsigned and the signed one); The cloud console gives 2 different API keys, one for each. In my Manifest file there is only the signed API key. I tried using the debug version of the APK (unsigned). GMaps still worked